# Extracting adjacency list from 2D and 3D skeleton images in python

Tags: python, graph, adjacency-list, skeleton-code

I have skeletonized 2D and 3D images as follows:

[2D skeleton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM1uA.png)

[3D skeleton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSoM0.png)

Now, I want to analyze the skeletons in python and obtain the following information:

1. The location of nodes.
2. The adjacency list.
3. The connectivity (the number of continuous skeletons in an image).

Is there any approach to do this in python?

Comment: The 3D is impossible unless you can generate an image looking from a different direction;

Comment: Thanks. The image j and Avizo do this for 3D skeletons (however, I want to get the information using python).

Comment: Whatever language you use, 3D is impossible without images looking from a different direction

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean by generating an image looking from a different direction? What would be the next step?

Comment: The standard would be a view from the front, a view from both sides and one from the back  i.e. a view from the four compass points.  From above and below may often be neccessary too.  See this diagram https://www.mdpi.com/applsci/applsci-11-07536/article_deploy/html/images/applsci-11-07536-g002-550.jpg